# Recursive method reverse string, why isn't the call working for the reverse method?

Tags: java, recursion

I have to reverse a string and make it in a recursive order. I was wondering why I can't call it. Also, would this be the correct way to reverse and print it out recursively?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseString
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.println("Please enter the string you want reversed:");
      Scanner str = new Scanner (System.in);
      String input = str.nextLine();
      System.out.println(input);

      reversedString recursive = new reversedString;
      System.out.println("Recursively reversed string: " + reversedString);
   }

   public static String recursive(String input)
   {
    if ((null == input) || (input.length()  <= 1)) 
    {
       return input;
    }
    return recursive(input.substring(1)) + input.charAt(0);
   }

}
```

Would like to thank Jace J McPherson for the fix. It was as simple as replacing the 
          reversedString recursive = new reversedString;
to 
          String reversedString = new recursive(input);

Comment: Post the code someone will fix the formatting for you.

Comment: @Musa I am working on that right now, it's pasting all funky and doesn't allow it to be posted. Hand writing the code as we speak.

Comment: What is `reversedString`? Your own datatype?

Comment: @Kuma Sadly, it's been a while since I've coded in java. I thought we had that line was to call a method. I guess not?

Comment: No, just paste it in as you have it in the editor then highlight the code and press ctrl+k.

Answer (score 0):

On line 12, change to

```
String reversedString = recursive(input);
```

Comment: Oh wow it compiled!! Thank you :] and my code worked! Appreciate the help !